# For-loop error - values not being entered into column

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with one column containing a bunch of sound file filenames (.wav). I would like to measure something within each sound file, and have each measurement listed in a second new column next to the corresponding filename.  In my code, each measurement is not being put into the second column.  If I take each line of the for-loop and run it independently with the values 1, 2, 3 etc substituted for i, the resulting dataframe has the output measurements correctly entered.

I have written a toy example below, which cannot be run without some wav files, but perhaps the problem can be spotted based on the code alone:

```
library(seewave); library(tuneR)
setwd("D:/wavs")

#make a dataframe containing a column of wav filenames
file_list <-data.frame(c("wav1.wav", "wav2.wav", "wav3.wav"))
colnames(file_list)[1] <-"filelist" #give it a sensible column name
file_list$filelist <-as.character(file_list$filelist) #convert from factor
file_list$mx <-NA #a new empty vector for the measurement results
str(file_list) #this is how it will look before adding measurements

#now read in each wav file, measure something,
#and put the outcome in the empty cell next to that corresponding filename.
for (i in length(file_list$filelist)){
  a <-as.character(file_list$filelist[[i]]) #this seemed to be a requirement, that 'wav1.wav' etc be a character
  temp <-readWave(a) #read the file using tuneR package
  mx <-max(range(temp@left)) #take some measurement from the left channel
  file_list$mx[[i]] <-mx #put it in a new column next to the original filename
  rm(mx); rm(temp); rm(a) #kill unnecessary things before starting again, for just in case
}
```

Needless to say, I have scoured the web and Stackoverflow for guidance without success, and tried a bunch of things (e.g. using `}next{`).  Perhaps I need something similar to: `file_list2$mx[i,] <-mx`.  Maybe some easy points for someone?  Thank you, I am always grateful for help on SO.

Comment: If you add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `data.frame()` call, you won't have to do those `as.character()` conversions.

Comment: put `rm(mx); rm(temp); rm(a)` outside the loop. On every iteration the previous value will be over-written, so you only have to remove the very last ones. Having it inside the loop won't cause problems, but makes it less efficient.

Comment: Thanks @AkselA, good tips for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that, You have not iterated the for loop. Means as per your code the for loop runs only one time i.e i=3. The correct code given below:

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list$filelist)){
  a <-as.character(file_list$filelist[[i]]) #this seemed to be a requirement, that 'wav1.wav' etc be a character
  temp <-readWave(a) #read the file using tuneR package
  mx <-max(range(temp@left)) #take some measurement from the left channel
  file_list$mx[[i]] <-mx #put it in a new column next to the original filename
  rm(mx); rm(temp); rm(a) #kill unnecessary things before starting again, for just in case
}
```

Hope this could help you !

Comment: Thanks @Ankur Singh.  Sigh...such a small error.  Thanks for noticing, and responding!

Answer (score 1):

How about a `tidyverse` solution?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data.frame(filelist=c("wav1.wav", "wav2.wav", "wav3.wav"), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  mutate(mx =  map_dbl(filelist, ~ readWave(.x)@left %>% max))
```

Comment: Very nice @Vlad C. Thanks for responding and putting me onto purrr.